# Tire damage needing replacement?

Tags: tires, hyundai, damage, sidewall-damage

[image]

Today I hit a curb and scarred the sidewall of my tire. Hoping it can be repaired but ready if I need to shell out the money for replacement. Got a few opinions from other forums and a tire shop in town, all pretty much said that I’m ok for now but to just check if it bubbles/warps at all. From what I can see it hasn’t punctured deep enough to damage cords. Any thoughts? It’s a 2013 Hyundai Elantra GT.

Answer (score 4):

I would agree with the opinions you received from the tyre shops. What you have is a scuff on a part of the tyre that does not contact the road. The important thing is that no cords or belting are damaged or exposed, and no bulges/bubbles/warps. This will be safe to drive on for the rest of the life of the rubber.

If you feel uncomfortable driving on it, replace it. Tyres are cheap, and if it helps you sleep at night - good value for money!